# how print Uri apk File in console android studio?

Tags: java, android, apk, uri, share

I designed **share butoon** in my application to share (**package application** *base.apk*) it between users without download it from Google Play store every time (especially if user dont connected or package internet may be limited); but after successfully share it with **device nearby share option** the receiver device appears  **File incomplete or not verified** [screenshot from received device appears the mistake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbLNr.png)

- This made me think of making sure the apk file **Uri** is safe before sharing it.Therefore, I need to print it on the Android Studio console and follow the process step by step to detect possible errors at any stage of sharing the application.
- As a reminder, I saved a copy of the apk package in the cache path, extracted from the application path source.

After the success of the process of obtaining a copy of the apk and writing it to the application cache directory.  The strange thing is that the integrity of the application package file fails and it is not possible to install it.

Comment: Note that if the app has been downloaded from Play Store most likely the app consists of multiple APK files. The base.apk will be not enough in such cases to install it on a second device.